# How to get user input using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking to prompt the user to enter his/her name at the beginning of a game I am building.

What is the best way to get input from the user in cocos2d?

Thank you,
Joey

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocos2d doesn't have any text input controls but you can easily add UIKit controls to the scene in Cocos2d 2.0

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myTextField];
```

You can use a UIAlertView with a text field embedded.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
//[alert release]; If not using ARC
```

To receive the events back from the UIAlertView you implement the **UIAlertViewDelegate**. In your header file add the delegate protocol to your interface

```
@interface BTMyScene : CCLayer <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then in your implementation file add any of the methods from the delegate protocol you want to receive notifications for. You probably want this one

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
     NSString *name = textField.text;
}
```

I recommend reading the documentation for [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) and [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html). You will see all the available methods that you can use.

Comment: The alert method is exactly what I am looking for.  One more thing, how would I access the string from the text field to store in a variable and is there an event fired when the user hits the done button that I can catch and do something when it is pressed?

Comment: Yes, you implement the UIAlertViewDelegate and then you can access the textfield through the AlertView

Comment: I have never implemented my own delegate, would you be willing to instruct me how to?

Comment: Just a fair warning if trying to invoke the keyboard freezes or crashes your app, try checking your deployment target to see that it is higher than iOS 4.0